# Modifying a deb package in Kali Linux

Tags: debian

What kind of knowledge should I gain to properly modify .deb package? I am using dpkg-deb to unpack and repack the package. But I am stuck at something called in /bin folder in extracted files. I am trying to modify flareget. So I did

```
dpkg-deb -x flareget.deb /flareget
```

then

```
dpkg-deb -e flareget.deb /flareget
```

I found a file named `flareget` but I can not able to identify which kind of file it is. When I open it with sublime it shows something like when we open an .exe file with hex editor. My intention to do with flareget is to tweak it as I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an executable specifically for Linux they are encoded in the Elf format where as in Windows they are in the PE format. The '-x' option using dpkg-deb will not be useful for repacking your modifications as a deb file however I have a solution:

```
wget http://flareget.com/files/flareget/debs/i386/flareget_4.2-92_i386.deb
mkdir flareget
mv flareget_4.2-92_i386.deb flareget/
cd flareget
mkdir extracted
dpkg-deb -R flareget_4.2-92_i386.deb extracted
cd extracted/usr/bin
readelf -h flareget
```

This will return something like this.

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           Intel 80386
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x8063010
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          3108188 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         8
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         31
  Section header string table index: 30
```

If you want to view all the information and offsets you can do this.

```
readelf -a flareget
```

You can use objdump as well to help with your reverse engineering by doing the following:

```
objdump -M intel --section .comment -d flareget
```

Obviously the comment section may not be very useful to you but you can change this to meet your needs. You can get a list of the different sections by doing:

```
objdump -h flareget
```

You will get output like this:

```
Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .interp       00000013  08048134  08048134  00000134  2**0
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  1 .note.ABI-tag 00000020  08048148  08048148  00000148  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  2 .note.gnu.build-id 00000024  08048168  08048168  00000168  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
```

With this you can reverse engineer the program by entering your own offsets and code by modifying the file using a hex editor. An easy one to use is called Bless.

```
apt-get -y install bless
```

It's a GUI application so It's quite easy to use.

You can also use strings to do a query for data you are looking to modify and get the offsets as well by doing the following.

```
strings -a -t x flareget | grep "Search Terms Here"
```

You can then navigate to these offsets and modify what you want especially ASCII strings are really easy to modify in the Elf and PE formats.

If you want to repackage the deb file after your modifications:

```
dpkg-deb -b extracted/ flareget_modified.deb
```

You could install the package you modified by:

```
dpkg -i flareget_modified.deb
```

Before reverse engineering any software please read [this article](https://ethics.csc.ncsu.edu/intellectual/reverse/study.php) for information on the legality surrounding the topic.